# Problem with Import object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto but not used protobuf compilation in OS High Sierra

Tags: python, tensorflow, protostuff

I have a problem in a OS terminal compiled: ./bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

object_detection/protos/input_reader.proto:5:1: warning: Import object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto but not used.

Anyone knows how can solve this bug?. I read in other similar post deleted or commented a line in one file, but it seems don´t compile anything do it this.

Answer (score 0):

it's not an error it's just a warning. You will also receive "warnings" in the following sections. For example, in the new version of Tensorflow, you will receive the warning that the training record will be deleted automatically. Do not get stuck in warnings, trouble if errors.